# Capture image and add to Grid View dynamically

Tags: android, gridview, camera, android-arrayadapter, onactivityresult

I have an activity containing a grid view. In this grid view, I add images that are captured from the camera/ taken from the gallery.

Currently, I have one button in the activity that provides a selector dialog prompting users to either capture a new image or select one from the gallery. In the onActivityResult(), I take this bitmap and add it to ArrayList of Bitmaps. Everytime this is done, a fresh grid is added to the grid view.

x objects in grid view --> user clicks on button capture (in activity)--> Bitmap gets captured--> new object added to grid view adapter (x+1) --> captured image is shown in that.

This code is working fine as is but now I want to remove this 'button' in the activity and shift it such that, when the user taps on each item, user can capture an image which is shown on that grid.

The Activity

```
 GridItem gridItem=new GridItem();
 list = new ArrayList<>();
 list.add(gridItem); //Currently grid view has only one view
 gridViewAdapter= new GridViewAdapter(ImageGridView.this, R.layout.row_gridview, list);
 gridView.setAdapter(gridViewAdapter);
```

The Grid View Adapter

```
public class GridViewAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<GridItem> {

    private Context mContext;
    private int layoutResourceId;
    private ArrayList<GridItem> mGridData = new ArrayList<GridItem>();

    public GridViewAdapter(Context mContext, int layoutResourceId, ArrayList<GridItem> mGridData) {
        super(mContext, layoutResourceId, mGridData);
        this.layoutResourceId = layoutResourceId;
        this.mContext = mContext;
        this.mGridData = mGridData;
    }


    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View row = convertView;
        final ViewHolder holder;

        if (row == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity) mContext).getLayoutInflater();
            row = inflater.inflate(layoutResourceId, parent, false);
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.btnAdd = (Button) row.findViewById(R.id.imgAdd);
            holder.btnRemove =(Button) row.findViewById(R.id.imgRemove);
            holder.imageView= (ImageView)row.findViewById(R.id.img);
            row.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) row.getTag();
        }

       holder.btnAdd.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
           @Override
           public void onClick(View v) {
               //Capture an image, Display bitmap in the image view
               //Display new view as a call to action for the user to add another image
               // Disable this button so user cannot add another image to same view
               GridItem gridItem=new GridItem();
               mGridData.add(gridItem);
               notifyDataSetChanged();
           }
       });

        holder.btnRemove.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                mGridData.remove(position);
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        });

       return row;
    }

    static class ViewHolder {
        TextView titleTextView;
        ImageView imageView;
        Button btnAdd, btnRemove;
    }
 }
```

In the activity, I am using a button that opens this dialog to pick the image from the activity. Once a bitmap is made, it gets added to a `GridItem object` and then added to the adapter and `notifyDataSetChanged()` is called. I want to essentially shift this method such that, the user clicks on individuals buttons(btnAdd) within each element/view to add an image to it dynamically.

```
private void selectImage() {
        final CharSequence[] items = {"Take Photo", "Choose from Gallery"};
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(mContext);
        builder.setTitle("Add picture of Prescription");
        builder.setItems(items, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int item) {
                if (items[item].equals("Take Photo")) {                    
                    File f = getOutputMediaFile();
                    mUri = Uri.fromFile(f);
                    Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                    intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, mUri);
                    startActivityForResult(intent, Constants.REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE);                    

                } else {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(
                            Intent.ACTION_PICK,
                            android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
                    intent.setType("image/*");
                    startActivityForResult(
                            Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select File"),
                            Constants.REQUEST_GALLERY);
            }
        });
        builder.show();
    }
```

I have tried to add the image picker dialog inside the adapter for my grid view but I am unable to make a `onActivityResult()` function so I don't know how to handle the results of the selection.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code that will help you to choose a any file from the device and then you can perform the action in onActivityResult as you want.

```
public void browseClick() {

    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT); 
    intent.setType("*/*"); 
    intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
    try {
        startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select a File to Upload"),FILE_SELECT_CODE);
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        System.out.println("browseClick :"+ex);
    }
}


@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
     if (requestCode == FILE_SELECT_CODE) {
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                try {
                    String newName = "", filename = "";
                    int filesize = 0;
                    Uri uri = data.getData();
                    if (filesize >= FILE_SIZE_LIMIT) {
                        Toast.makeText(
                                this,
                                "The selected file is too large. Selet a new file with size less than 2mb",
                                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    } else {
                        String mimeType = getContentResolver().getType(uri);
                        if (mimeType == null) {
                            String path = getPath(this, uri);
                            if (path == null) {
                                filename = FilenameUtils
                                        .getName(uri.toString());
                            } else {
                                File file = new File(path);
                                filename = file.getName();
                            }
                        } else {
                            Uri returnUri = data.getData();
                            Cursor returnCursor = getContentResolver().query(
                                    returnUri, null, null, null, null);
                            int nameIndex = returnCursor
                                    .getColumnIndex(OpenableColumns.DISPLAY_NAME);
                            int sizeIndex = returnCursor
                                    .getColumnIndex(OpenableColumns.SIZE);
                            returnCursor.moveToFirst();
                            filename = returnCursor.getString(nameIndex);
                            String size = Long.toString(returnCursor
                                    .getLong(sizeIndex));
                        }


                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
}
```

You can set the type of file that you want to select using  "intent.setType()" method.